# not able to verify in-app update with google play console

Tags: android, in-app-update, google-play-internal-testing, google-publisher-tag

I am trying to test the feature of in-app upgrade of android and to do so i have to upload the app in internal track. In order to do so i have made below required changes

**1. enable the setting in google play store to participate in the internal testing**

[image]

**2. upload the app build in internal testing track**

[image]

**3. I have downloaded the app from the google play store**

[image]

after that to check the in app update if i tried to change the version number and flash it into internal testing then it throws an error.

I have been trying to check this since more than a month but no luck , can one please help me out here

[image]

Comment: I think you need to publish to a track, but I don't think the internal testing track counts as the artifacts there are not reviewed. Try an alpha or beta track.

Comment: @Pierre i tried to promote the internal version to alpha and now the status is in-review lets see what happens next